# Elementary Linear Space Proof/Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have started reading **An Introduction to Linear Algebra and Tensors** by M.A. Akivis and V.V. Goldberg.  I am trying to grasp exactly what the definition of a linear space is because I am not certain how to interpret the definition in the book.

The best way to explain my difficulty may be an example.  One of the book's exercises is to determine if the set of vectors X = (x1, x2,...,xn) such that x1 + x2 + ... + xn = 0 is or is not a linear space.

As far as I understand, the criteria for a linear space boils down to the fact that the set of vectors comprising a linear space is closed under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication.  But my problem is that I am not sure about the definition of closed.

When I started trying to solve the exercise, I calculated that x1 + x2 + ... + xn = 0 ⇒ xn = (-x1) + (-x2) + ... + (-xn-1).  I thought that this might offer proof that the set X is closed under addition.  But is that actually what they mean by "closed" or am I way off?

For example, how is this same set of vectors closed under scalar multiplication?  If you multiply any of these vectors by an arbitrary real number λ, doesn't the result give you a different vector that falls outside the boundary defined by x1 + x2 + ... + xn = 0?

I feel that if I could get straight on what is meant by "closed," I might be able to start making progress.  But I just am not comfortable with the definition as I currently understand it and I wonder if anybody can disambiguate what is and is not a linear space.  Thanks

Comment: To check for closure under addition, add two vectors $\vec x=(x_1,..,x_n)$ and $\vec y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ in $X$ to get $\vec{x}+\vec y =(x_1+y_1,...,x_n+y_n)$.  Is $\vec x +\vec y$ in $X$?  By the way, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Let me denote by $\mathrm{E}$ the following set: $$\mathrm{E}=\{X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n,x_1+\cdots+x_n=0\}.$$ You are asked to show that $\mathrm{E}$ is a linear space. As you write, $\mathrm{E}$ is a linear space if—essentially—the following two conditions hold:

– if $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$ are vectors in $\mathrm{E}$ so that, in particular, $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then their sum $\mathrm{X}+\mathrm{Y}$, which is well-defined *as an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$*, *is in fact a vector in $\mathrm{E}$*: this is by definition what it means for $\mathrm{E}$ to be closed under the operation $+$ of sums, that the sum, calculated in $\mathbb{R}^n$, of vectors that lie in $\mathrm{E}$, is in fact in $\mathrm{E}$—another word for *closed* under sum would be *stable* under sum;

– if $\mathrm{X}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ and if $\lambda$ is a real number, then the product $\lambda\cdot\mathrm{X}$, which is well-defined *as an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$*, *is in fact a vector in $\mathrm{E}$*: this is by definition what it means to be closed under scalar multiplication: that the scalar multiplication, calculated in $\mathbb{R}^n$, of a vector that lies in $\mathrm{E}$ by a scalar or real number, lies in fact in $\mathrm{E}$: again, a different word for *closed* under scalar multiplication would be *stable* under scalar multiplication.

I will return later to why I wrote essentially. Now let $\mathrm{X}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\mathrm{Y}=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ be vectors in $\mathrm{E}$. By definition of the sum $+$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, their sum $\mathrm{X}+\mathrm{Y}$ is the vector $\mathrm{Z}=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $$z_1=x_1+y_1,z_2=x_2+y_2,\ldots,z_n=x_n+y_n.$$ We say that addition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined coordinate-wise because the coordinates of the sum $\mathrm{X}+\mathrm{Y}$ are the sums of the coordinates of $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$. We have to show that $\mathrm{Z}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$. By definition of , this means that $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=0.$$ Now $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=\sum_{i=1}^n z_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i).$$ However, this is simply a sum of *real* numbers. By commutativity and associativity of sums of real numbers, we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)=(x_1+\cdots+x_n)+(y_1+\cdots+y_n).$$ Now $\mathrm{X}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ so that $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$ by definition of $\mathrm{E}$. Similarly, $y_1+\cdots+y_n=0$ since $\mathrm{Y}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$. Finally, $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=(x_1+\cdots+x_n)+(y_1+\cdots+y_n)=0+0=0.$$ Thus $\mathrm{Z}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ as required. Hence, $\mathrm{E}$ is closed under sum.

Now let $\mathrm{X}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ and let $\lambda$ be a real number. By definition of scalar multiplication $\cdot$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\cdot\mathrm{X}$ is the vector $\mathrm{Z}=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $$z_1=\lambda\times x_1,\ldots,z_n=\lambda x_n$$ where $\times$ denotes multiplication of *real numbers*, that is, usual multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$. For simplicity and as is the usage, I will sometimes omit $\times$ from the notation and write $\lambda\times x_i=\lambda x_i$. Now we have to show that $\mathrm{Z}$ lies in $\mathrm{E}$. By definition of $\mathrm{E}$, this means that $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=0.$$ We know what the $z_i$'s are: $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=\sum_{i=1}^n z_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda x_i).$$ But this is a sum of real numbers. This time, because multiplication $\times$ is distributive with respect to addition $+$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda x_i=\lambda\times\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\lambda\times(x_1+\cdots+x_n).$$ But $\mathrm{X}$ lies in $\mathrm{E}$ so that $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$. As a result, $$z_1+\cdots+z_n=\lambda\times 0=0.$$ Thus $\mathrm{Z}$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ as required. Hence $\mathrm{E}$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Now there is a minor caveat if we wish to conclude that $\mathrm{E}$ is a linear space. In addition to the two conditions mentioned above, we also have to show that the zero vector $0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in $\mathrm{E}$. Indeed it follows tautologically that the *empty set* $\emptyset$ satisfies the two conditions but it is *not* a linear space because it does not contain the zero vector. So we have to show that the zero vector $0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ lies in $\mathrm{E}$. By definition, $$0_{\mathbb{R}^n}=(0,\ldots,0)$$ where the zeros on the right are the *real number* zero. We have to show that $$0+\cdots+0=0$$ where the left-hand side is a sum of real numbers all equal to zero. This is of course obvious. Thus $\mathrm{E}$ is a linear space as required.

The word *closed* may be ambiguous if you are used to topology where it has a very different meaning; maybe the word *stable* is less so. Linear spaces are *stable* under the operations of sum and scalar multiplication because you can perform these operations on vectors of linear spaces without leaving the linear space in which these vectors lie.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: You are welcome.